# vba code does not work on the first number in the loop but okay for the left numbers in the loop

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, formatting, vba

I want to change the color of cells automatically if a cell is 10% bigger or smaller than either the corresponding cell that is in the same row but three columns to the left or the corresponding cell (in the same row and column) in the workbook '2014variance.xlsx'.

```
Sub testing1()

Dim x As Integer

Dim y As Integer

For x = 35 To 5 Step -3

For y = 11 To 76 Step 1

If IsNumeric(Cells(y, x).Value) Then

If VBA.Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) < VBA.Abs(0.9 * Cells(y, x - 3).Value) Or _

   VBA.Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) > VBA.Abs(1.1 * Cells(y, x - 3)) Then

     Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 22

ElseIf VBA.Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) < VBA.Abs(0.9 *            
      Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x)) Or _

       VBA.Abs(Cells(y, x).Value) > VBA.Abs(1.1 * 
       Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, x)) Then

     Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 42


End If

End If

Next y

Next x

End Sub
```

The code works fine except for the Column 2. I understand that it will not be colored under the first if condition. However, I want it to work under the 'ElseIf' condition. Column 2 is supposed to have blue color because those numbers are lower than 90% of '2014variance.xlsx'. How can I do that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a mock environment, I took your sub procedure and went through the code. It looked like you were overextending the VBA's [Abs function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262673(v=vs.60).aspx); the maths were not achieving what you wanted. I don't think you intended for `-0.9` to be within 10% of `0.9`. I added a couple of vars and tightened up some sections.

```
Sub testing1()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, wbws1 As Double, c2 As Double, c5 As Double
    Dim xWS As Worksheet

    Set xWS = Workbooks("2014variance.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ActiveSheet
        For x = 35 To 5 Step -3
            For y = 11 To 76 Step 1
                If IsNumeric(.Cells(y, x).Value2) Then
                    If CBool(.Cells(y, x).Value2) Then   '<>0
                        c2 = .Cells(y, x - 3).Value2
                        c5 = .Cells(y, x).Value2
                        If (Abs(c2 - c5) / c5) > 0.1 Then

                            .Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 22

                        Else
                            wbws1 = xWS.Cells(y, x).Value2
                            If (Abs(wbws1 - c5) / c5) > 0.1 Then

                                .Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 42

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next y
        Next x
    End With

    Set xWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

That uses the Abs function but only to gain a 0 -> 0.10 from -0.10 -> 0. It works well on my mockup environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Your code works. However, the first column is still been ignored by VBA. The spreadsheet is listed as January to December in 2015. And I want VBA to compare each month in 2015 with 2014. From Feb to Dec works fine, but the January, which is column 2, there is no color change in that column. Do you know is there any issues?

Comment: For x = 35 to 2, step -3 will cause 'application defined or object defined' error. I think it is because I have cells(y,x-3).value, and x - 3 would be -1, which is not exist in columns. So I put x = 35 to 5, step -3. But since i put x=5, x =2 cannot be calculated. How to solve the problem?